# How can I trigger dynamic tab whenever I click on static tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, triggers, element

I have an example HTML like this:

```
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="tab1">
     <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="tab2">
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages</div>
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
</div>
```

And the JQuery:

$(function() {

```
 $("#tab2").html($("#tab1").html());

 //event click for tab2
 $("#tab2 li a[data-toggle='tab']").on("click",function(){
      $("#tab1 a[href="+$(this).attr("href")+"]").trigger("click");
 });

//event click for tab1
$("#tab1 li a[data-toggle='tab']").on("click",function(){
      $("#tab2 a[href="+$(this).attr("href")+"]").trigger("click");
 });
```

});

Tab1 is static tab, tab2 is dynamic elements (copy html from tab1).

All I want to do is whenever tab1 is clicked, tab2 also be clicked and vice versa. But I have no luck. Is there anybody can help me? thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/qq6tyqo9/1/

Comment: Can you prepare a fiddle for the same? And one more thing what is the need of such thing? If two tabs can remain open than what is the point of having tabs??

Comment: looks like bootstrap, you should remove one of the tags and replace it with bootstrap attract the people more relevant

Comment: @GHOST93 I tried to make a very simple example For my problem. Actually I'm making a responsive tabs that converted to dropdown, i need 2 tabs synchronized for the case resize browser window.

Comment: @ALau: it's totally bootstrap. What you mean about remove tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let make a trick with class

```
$("#tab2").html($("#tab1").html());


 $("#tab2 li a[data-toggle='tab']").on("click",function(){
    $("#tab1 li").removeClass("active");
    $("#tab1 a[href="+$(this).attr("href")+"]").parent().addClass("active");
 });

$("#tab1 li a[data-toggle='tab']").on("click",function(){
    $("#tab2 li").removeClass("active");
    $("#tab2 a[href="+$(this).attr("href")+"]").parent().addClass("active");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this-

```
 var a = '1';var b ='1';
     $("#tab2").on("click","li a[data-toggle='tab']",function(){
    console.log(b);
    if(b==1){a=2;
          $("#tab1 a[href="+$(this).attr("href")+"]").click();}else{a=1;b=1;}
     });

    //event click for tab1
    $("#tab1").on("click","li a[data-toggle='tab']",function(){
    console.log(a);
    if(a==1){
    b=2;
          $("#tab2 a[href="+$(this).attr("href")+"]").click();
    }else{b=1;a=1;}
     });
```